# Who can play on www.pokerstars.it?

Tags: online

Only italian players are allowed to register on www.pokerstars.it or anyone can legally register and play?

Comment: The PokerStart.it site FAQ (http://www.pokerstars.it/en/poker/room/faq/) would seem to be a more appropriate place to ask about the policies of another service. They'll be more authoritative and up to date than asking here. "**Are non-Italian residents allowed to play on this site?**
No. This site is reserved exclusively for Italian residents/citizens who can provide a valid (fiscal code) and can provide proof of their identity, either with an Italian ID card, Italian driver’s license or Italian passport."

Comment: @Robert Cartaino: it's only localized because, in this case, they don't allow players outside of *.it*.  But there are other sites where this isn't the case.  For example: Q: *"who can play on Winamax.fr?"* A: *"anyone in europe"*  (it's just an example to make a point: an online site concerning a lot of europeans isn't too localized). If people keep downvoting and closing questions that have answers then the 4 questions / per on average, in freefall since the 2nd day the site went live, will keep freefalling and it's StackExchange Poker that can be closed...  Just my $0.02 continuation bet ;)

Comment: @user988052 Leaving poor quality questions open in the hopes that they will draw interest is not the way to improve this site.  Also, keep in mind that this is a private beta, so the site really hasn't gone "live" yet.

Comment: @Beofett: my point was that this is not a poor question but a very legitimate question (with legal implications etc.) that is **very** common on big poker forums because a lot of players want to know the answer to this.  And it's not "too localized": it does concern most players: it's not because, in this case, only italian players can play on *pokerstars.it* that the answer is not interesting to a lot of players (especially seen the gigantic fish pond and the amazing money to be made on *pokerstars.it* due to the very bad playing field).

Comment: @user988052: Don't get caught up in the close reason. "Too localized" because stating the policies of another website is only useful at that time. "General Reference" would be more applicable. If you want to know the policies of another website, it is better to than to ask here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Italian players in general, if you have registered account in for example USA you can't play